# How to point DNS CNAME to external GitHub Pages domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, github

I have repository on GitHub with GitHub Pages set up. If I go to `myusername.github.io/my-repo` everything works correctly. But, I would like to have my own domain name that looks better than that one.

I purchased a domain name: `mydomain.site`. I created a CNAME record that points `www` to `myusername.github.io`. But if I now go to `www.mydomain.site/my-repo`, I get GitHub's 404 screen. The same happens if I go to just `www.mydomain.site`.

Ideally, I would like users to go to `www.mydomain.site` and see the content from `myusername.github.io/my-repo`, but it would also be acceptable if they had to go to `www.mydomain.site/my-repo`. I don't want to simply redirect them, my domain name must remain in the address bar. How do I achieve this?

(myusername, my-repo and mydomain are obviously not the real names that I used, I need to keep them private)

Comment: https://docs.github.com/ko/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: @tripleee thanks, that is indeed the fix, although you should post the english version

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting `www.mydomain.site` in the custom domain setting in the Pages section of my GitHub repository settings.